# NodeJS process remote image without downloading it

Tags: node.js, image-processing

In NodeJS I need to create an API for remote image processing. Using the URL of an image I need to get all the relevant data (width, height, file size,etc) and then process it using a library like Graphics magick. The problem is, that gm always returns this error

{ [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }

The code I used is

```
request.get(imageUrl, function (err, res, body) {

   var buffer = new Buffer(body,'binary');

   gm(buffer)
    .size(function (err, size) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('width = ' + size.width);
        console.log('height = ' + size.height);
      } else
        console.log(err)
    });


});
```

The question is: How can i process an image without downloading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general specification for image meta data across different image file formats. So in most cases, you will have to rely on the remote server's API serving you image meta data without the full image information or - which is the case you want to avoid - just fetch the full image and do the calculation yourself. 
If you do not need the exact image dimensions or ratio right away, you may estimate them by sending an HTTP *HEAD* request and interpreting the *Content-Type* and *Content-Length* HTTP response headers.

Regarding the *ENOENT* error, it seems like this could either be about missing data (Is *body* set correctly?) or a missing ImageMagick installation: [Error: spawn ENOENT while using GM in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222116/error-spawn-enoent-while-using-gm-in-node)

Comment: I do need the exact image dimensions, so I need to fetch the  full image. The body is 
<Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 20 50 55 42 4c 49 43 20 22 2d 2f 2f 57 33 43 2f 2f 44 54 44 20 48 54 4d 4c 20 34 2e 30 31 20 54 72 61 6e 73 69 ...>
I have installed both ImageMagick (v 0.1.3) and gm(v 1.9.0)
How can I fetch the full image in order to calculate its dimensions?